# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Text:'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to store an image into a SQL Server database. I keep getting the error around `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

```
string fileName = ofd.FileName;

SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = @"Server = Big-PAPI-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database = LOGO; Trusted_Connection = True";

cnn.Open();

// inserts image and name
string prompt_id = txt_result.ToString();
Image image = pictureBox1.Image;

string query = $"INSERT INTO dbo.LOGO (Logo_Prompt,image) VALUES({ prompt_id} , {image})";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Insertservice(prompt_id,image);
MessageBox.Show("Item inserted  !");
cnn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [parameterize](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx) your queries:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.LOGO (Logo_Prompt,image) VALUES(@prompt_id, @image)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prompt_id", prompt_id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", image);
```

And as [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) suggests better pass parameters with explicit db type:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@prompt_id", SqlDbType.....).Value = prompt_id;
command.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.....).Value = image;
```

Comment: **Parametrize - YES!!** But you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...