# Use method Replace() on table dynamic JSON using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sql-server

I want to use method `Replace()` to change double quote  `"`  by single quote  `'`   in my code C# for many reasons.

**For example** in SQL Server I can't insert in column `nvarchar` a text contains a single quote.

```
INSERT INTO table_ VALUES('can't use');
```

So I figured out I should use

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
INSERT INTO table_ VALUES("can't use");
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

But the problem in my JSON  tables contains  single and double quotes that I can't insert in my database. That why I want to use method `Replace()`. But it throw error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'No overload for method 'Replace' takes '2' arguments'

**My code**:

```
public SqlConnection con;
public SqlCommand cmd;
public SqlDataAdapter da;
public DataSet ds;
public DataTable dt;
public SqlDataReader rdr;
public SqlParameter pr;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection("data source = (local);initial catalog = DB; integrated security = true;");
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    WebClient api = new WebClient();
    string JSON = api.DownloadString("http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ma&apiKey=4fff1c0a541c43d99e4a6f319d191fca");
    dynamic myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JSON);
    var qt = '"';

    for (int i = 0; i < myObj.articles.Count; i++)
    { 
        cmd.CommandText = "" +
            " SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;" +
            " INSERT INTO NEWS VALUES(" +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].source.id.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].name.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].author.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].title.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].description.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].url.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].urlToImage.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].publishedAt.Replace("'", qt) + qt + "," +
            "" + qt + myObj.articles[i].content.Replace("'", qt) + qt + ")" +
            " SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**My SQL table**

```
create table news
(
    id int primary key identity(1,1),
    source_id nvarchar(1000)null,
    source_name nvarchar(1000)null,
    author nvarchar(100)null,
    title nvarchar(1000)null,
    description_ nvarchar(4000)null,
    url  nvarchar(1000)null,
    urlToImage nvarchar(1000)null,
    publishedAt date null,
    content nvarchar(4000) null
)
```

Comment: Use parameters. Then you won't have this problem.

Comment: Double quotes won't help you. They enclose identifiers in SQL server, not string literals. And what are you gonna do, if you have a string with single and double quotes? As @pinkfloydx33 already pointed out, you're on a completely wrong way here. Use parameterized queries. That will fix your current problem (and also some more).

Comment: @stickybit how can i use them.. please  if you could show me an example

Comment: Use your favorite web search engine of the search of this site. There's plenty of explanations and example out there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quote handling in a SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644703/single-quote-handling-in-a-sql-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your table scheme I would assume that JSON you are fetching has number for `myObj.articles[i].source.id` which will be parsed to `int` which in turn does not have `Replace` method:

```
var json = "{'id':1}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
obj.id.Replace("1", ""); // throws RuntimeBinderException: No overload for method 'Replace' takes 2 arguments
```

So just remove `Replace` call for it.

As for parameterized queries there is a lot  of information on this topic, for example you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237681/2501279) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7505842/2501279).

Also I would recommend to introduce some class which will represent your JSON scheme and deserialize to it, not `dynamic`.